# $watch in directives and activate directive on click

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

My basic problem is that I have a d3 graph inside a directive and I want it to show when a button submit is pressed. The d3 code inside a directive is wrapped into a `promise.then` because it has to fetch data from an `$http.get(...)` request.

Now my strategy is to have: a- a button with an `ng-click` attribute linked to a function `chnagePresent()` in my controller; b - having a variable `$scope.present` which take the value `true` or `false` according to whether the directive should show the graph or not; c-a `$watch` element inside the directive, bound to the `$scope.present` in the controller, with an `if` statement inside the callback function. If `$scope.present` is equal to true then the directive is fired, otherwise nothing is done (here just a dummy message is printed to the console).

The code looks like the following:

Directive:

```
.directive('ngGraphfingerprint',['getGraphsService',function(getGraphsService){

      return{

        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {},
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){

            var expression = scope.present

            scope.$watch(expression,
              function(newValue){

                if (newValue === true){

                  // var dataset = [

                  //   {'startYear' : '2005-01-12',
                  //   'label' : 'green',
                  //   'value' : 0.6,
                  //   'ceo' : 'Marcus Tetha'},
                  //   {'startYear' : '2005-01-12',
                  //   'label' : 'green',
                  //   'value' : 0.6,
                  //   'ceo' : 'Marcus Bo'},
                  //   {'startYear' : '2007-06-07',
                  //   'label' : 'red',
                  //   'value' : 0.9,
                  //   'ceo' : 'Marcus Alpha'},
                  //   {'startYear' : '2011-03-04',
                  //   'label' : 'red',
                  //   'value' : 0.03,
                  //   'ceo' : 'Marcus Gamma'},
                  //   {'startYear' : '2011-07-28',
                  //   'label' : 'yellow',
                  //   'value' : 0.1,
                  //   'ceo' : 'Marcus Beta'}

                  // ];

                  getGraphsService.FunctionF().prom.then(

                    var w = 750;
                    var h = 400;
                    var padding = 30;


                    var svg = d3.select(element[0])
                                .append('svg')
                                .attr('width',w)
                                .attr('height',h);

                    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                                  .domain([new Date('2004-01-01'),new Date('2014-12-31')])
                                  .range([padding*2.5,w-padding*0.5]);

                    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                  .domain(dataset.map(function(d){return d.ceo;}))
                                  .rangeBands([h - padding, padding]);

                    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                  .scale(yScale)
                                  .orient('left')
                                  .ticks(4);

                    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                  .scale(xScale)
                                  .orient('bottom')
                                  .ticks(d3.time.years)
                                  .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y'));


                    var axisStyle = {'fill': 'none', 'stroke': 'black','shape-rendering': 'crispEdges','font-family':'sans-serif','font-size': '11px'};

                    svg.append('g')
                          .style(axisStyle)
                          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
                          .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
                          .call(xAxis);

                    svg.append('g')
                          .style(axisStyle)
                          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding*2.5 + ',0)')
                          .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
                          .call(yAxis);

                    svg.selectAll('rect')
                       .data(dataset)
                       .enter()
                       .append('rect')
                       .attr('x',function(d){return xScale(new Date(d.startYear));})
                       .attr('y',function(d){return yScale(d.ceo)+yScale.rangeBand()/2-10;})
                       .attr('height',20)
                       .attr('width',20)
                       .attr('fill',function(d){return d.label;});

                    svg.selectAll('text.label')
                      .data(dataset)
                      .enter()
                      .append('text')
                      .attr('class','label')
                      .attr('x',function(d){return xScale(new Date(d.startYear)) + 10;})
                      .attr('y',function(d){return yScale(d.ceo)+yScale.rangeBand()/2;})
                      .text(function(d){
                        return d.startYear;
                      })
                      .on('mouseout',function(){d3.select(this).style('opacity','0');})
                      .on('mouseover',function(){d3.select(this).style('opacity','1');});

                  )

                  }else{

                    console.log('Nothing changed!');

                  }

              });
```

Controller:

```
$scope.present = false;

        $scope.changePresent = function(){

          $scope.present = true;
          console.log($scope.present);

        };
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-graphfingerprint="present" val="data"></div>
```

Now what the code above didn't work. A simple $watch inside the directive did not work either, so I am wondering if there is something else I should pay attention to when using $watch inside a directive. My editor also doesn't seem to like the `promise.then` method inside the `$watch` callback function.
But basically I don't even know if my strategy of using `$watch` is the correct one in this case. Can anyone help me?

If you need any clarification regarding the problem please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you've got there is that the directive has an isolate scope (`scope: {}`) and you're trying to access the present property of the parent scope.

Either remove the isolate scope from the directive or reference the present property in the isolate scope:

```
myModule.directive('graphfingerprint', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : { present: '=graphfingerprint'}, 

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('present', function(newValue){
            });
        }
    };
});
```